# Possible to get open graph data for comments box?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to get a list of comments, or at least a count of the number of comments that have been left on a website with the Facebook comments widget?

The widget I am using is placed inside an iFrame Facebook application.

Here is the XFBML which is being parsed by the Facebook Javascript API:

```
<fb:comments xid="fbtest"></fb:comments>
```

Would the xid parameter have anything to do with it? As far as I can tell, there are no other possible parameters. How would one query the open graph url (http://graph.facebook.com/QUERY) to access this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with FQL:

```
select post_id, text from comment where xid="fbtest"
```

see [`comment`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment) table

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I was so busy looking through all the docs for open graph I didn't even think to check the REST API.